# Redis connection refused between Vagrant and Docker

Tags: docker, redis, vagrant

I have a docker like this:

```
version: '3.5'

services:

  RedisServerA:
    container_name: RedisServerA
    image: redis:3.2.11
    command: "redis-server --port 26379"
    volumes:
      - ../docker/redis/RedisServerA:/data
    ports:
      - 26379:26379
    expose:
      - 26379

  RedisServerB:
    container_name: RedisServerB
    image: redis:3.2.11
    command: "redis-server --port 6379"
    volumes:
      - ../docker/redis/RedisServerB:/data
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    expose:
      - 6379
```

Now I do a `vagrant ssh` and do

```
ping RedisServerA
ping RedisServerB
```

They both work.

Now I try to connect to the redis server:

```
redis-cli -h RedisServerB
```

Works fine

Then I try to connect to the other

```
redis-cli -h RedisServerA -p 26739
```

It says:

```
Could not connect to Redis at RedisServerA:26739: Connection refused
Could not connect to Redis at RedisServerA:26739: Connection refused
```

Twice.

What am I missing here?

Comment: there are a few things: can you post the responses of the 2 ping commands? you should not be able to find a container by name outside of the docker network. which is what you are doing and I would like to understand how. Second, you don't need to change the internal port where redis is running: use "redis-server --port 6379" in both containers and then just change the mappings to different ports on the host. Since you seem to connect directly to the containers you don't even need the port mappings. The port mappings are useful if you try to connect to something like "localhost:26379"

Comment: @Mihai I added themto my hosts so they exist

Comment: checkout the answer from @DavidMaze. It is exactly what I tried to say but better organized. Also don't add containers to host. It doesn;t work that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically in this setup you'd let each container run on its "natural" port.  For connections from outside Docker you need the `ports:` mapping, and you'd access a container via its published port on the host's IP address.  For connections between Docker containers (assuming they're on the same network, and if you used bare `docker run`, you manually created that network), you use the container name and the container's internal port number.

We can clean up the `docker-compose.yml` file by removing some unnecessary lines (`container_name:` and `expose:` don't really have a practical effect) and letting the image run its default `command:` on the default port, and only remapping with `ports:`.  We'd get:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  RedisServerA:
    image: redis:3.2.11
    volumes:
      - ../docker/redis/RedisServerA:/data
    ports:
      - 26379:6379
  RedisServerB:
    image: redis:3.2.11
    volumes:
      - ../docker/redis/RedisServerB:/data
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
```

Between containers, you'd use the default port

```
redis-cli -h RedisServerA
redis-cli -h RedisServerB
```

From outside Docker you'd use the server's host name and the published ports

```
redis-cli -h server.example.com -p 23679
redis-cli -h server.example.com
```